# 1-Methyl-4-nitrobenzene proton NMR spectrum confusion

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy

[image: 1-methyl-4-nitrobenzene]

I wanted to analyse and suggest the peaks for the NMR spectrum and ran into a problem.

I knew that the methyl $\ce{CH3}$ produces a singlet peak with integration $3$ but when I ran into the benzene protons, I thought that the two equivalent protons (one on each side) would split into a doublet (considering if coupling occurs through 3 bonds or fewer only).

So this was my solution to the problem:

- s, $\ce{3H}$, integrated $3$, ppm $2.0$ due to $\ce{CH3}$ group.
- d, $\ce{3H}$, integrated $2$, ppm $7.2$ due to $\ce{H}$ on benzene furthest from $\ce{NO2}$.
- d, $\ce{3H}$, integrated $2$, ppm $7.9$ due to $\ce{H}$ on benzene closest to $\ce{NO2}$.

However, the spectrum answer given by the mark scheme was as such:

[image]

Where have I made a mistake?

Comment: The 1H NMR spectrum of *para*-disubstituted benzenes is not as simple as the (n+1) rule predicts, because of complicated effects. But to a first approximation, a doublet is much more accurate than the supposed triplet given in the mark scheme. see e.g. https://www.chem.wisc.edu/areas/reich/nmr/05-hmr-15-aabb.htm (Ctrl-F for "*para*-disub") or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_inequivalence#para-Disubstituted_benzenes You can see the NMR spectrum of this specific compound at https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/spectra/fnmr/FNMR011092.PDF

Comment: In the 1H NMR spectrum of *p*-disubstituted benzenes, the couplings to consider among protons in ortho, meta, and para relationship to each other.  Depending on the nature of your sample and the experimental conditions (e.g., resolution / how many data points per ppm the spectrometer records), the signals of the AA'XX' system *might* look different (simpler).  Cf. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/73434/1h-nmr-of-p-methoxy-phenol-32-possible-lines as follow-up of https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/73328/what-is-the-proton-nmr-spectrum-of-p-methoxyphenol.